# Update all fields in a firestore document

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update all records at once in a document. I will be sending whole form data from angular services to this cloud function even if i have changed only one value in the form. I have been able to write the get all user and get one user at a time cloud function successfully but i am a bit confused with update function. Here is my create function

createClients

```
exports.addClient = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if(req.body.company != null && req.body.abbrev != null && req.body.contact != null && req.body.phone != null && req.body.email != null && req.body.contactDate != null || 
    req.body.company != undefined && req.body.abbrev != undefined && req.body.contact != undefined && req.body.phone != undefined && req.body.email != undefined && req.body.contactDate != undefined) {
        let docId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 00000));
        let newClient = {
            "company": req.body.company,
            "abbrev": req.body.abbrev,
            "contact": req.body.contact,
            "phone": req.body.phone,
            "email": req.body.email,
            "contactDate": req.body.contactDate
        }
        usersClients.add(newClient).then(snapshot => {
            res.send(200, {
                "message": "Client was successfully created"
            })
        });
    } else {
        res.send(400, {
            "message": "All fields are required"
        })
    }
});
```

How can i write the function that will update all values at once of the above created cloud function.

Comment: The documentation describes how to update a document. Is there something about that which is not working for you? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Comment: @DougStevenson I went through this documentation and right now when i am looking at the code in documentation and my code i get a little bit confused as to where am i supposed to exactly use the update function.